# What is Stackoverflow's definition for research?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, rant

I just made a question which is research based - requires logic and references.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400159/suggestion-on-java-ee-development-please/12400233#12400233

It has been flagged for moderator attention.

I have given to the community but, when it comes to getting it back, there are bunch of users who act like they are after 'civic duty' badge or wants to be 'deputy'.

Another question was :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263787/how-to-integrate-dhl-api-in-php-website

I understand my second question does not reflect majority of the community but, then what is purpose of stackoverflow?

Whereas questions asking for a simple route gets more of +votes and does not get closed! That is not even researched based, it just requires an answer called RTFM!

We all develop, understand, share and contribute. That is how community works.

Maybe a time to add Flag for moderator's attention to help someone who might need assistance? and not just to close the damn thread just because it does not suit someone's priority!

Comment: It wasn't closed because of a lack of research. It was closed because the question baits subjective answers.

Comment: That is yet another way to say it. So, what else is Stackoverflow there for?

Comment: @Mysticial How do you justify this question then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314300/zend-framework-1-vs-zend-framework-2 ?

Comment: @KarmicDice Hm? The question is closed, why would anyone need to justify it?

Comment: with just 1 vote? :) That too mod with a star did it.

Comment: @KarmicDice Again, I fail to see your point.

Comment: and how do you define constructive? that guy asked which is more better? How? what are the changes? updates?

Comment: @KarmicDice I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: It's definitely a fuzzy line. Some people have lower thresholds for "not constructive" than others. And I can't say I agree with all the closures.

Comment: KarmicDice, I also want to point out that closing isn't the same on SE as it is on forums. Closing just puts the question into a special "hold status" so it doesn't get answers while problems with it are being fixed. In short, closing is not permanent, not at all, and I want to emphasize that I really think your question could be fixed and possibly voted to be reopened, which could lead you to getting much, *much* better answers! Hope this helps.

Comment: @jmort253 Yes it does.

Comment: @KarmicDice I see your point. Asking questions in SO is not easy. You have to learn how to ask questions so they don't get closed. Despite all the pain this causes you will probably will be writting better questions. Anyway I am also with you that some questions with a lot of upvotes are really effortless and that's kind of unfair. It is our mission to flag those or downvote.

Answer (score 21):

### Summary:

Don't ask our community of experts for books. Ask our experts for *solutions*.

Also, this may still be off-topic on Stack Overflow, but you might chat the Programmers SE team on [The Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) to see if it would be on-topic there, after some nice, constructive edits, that is! Whatever you do, don't just ask! I'm not an expert on their scope, and this is just a suggestion!

---

### Detailed Explanation:

The question you asked is a classic, textbook example of a recommendation question, as well as a poll/list question. In other words, you're not asking our community of experts for a *solution*. Instead, you're asking our community of experts to provide you with a list of other places to go to find your solution. This is not what Stack Overflow is about.

Think about the last time you Googled a solution and ended up on a forum, with several pages of posts which didn't provide you with the information you needed. Sometimes we get lucky and find the answers we seek buried in the sea of non-answers, but many times we search through pages of data only to be led straight back to the drawing board.

Since your question asks for a list of things, it's not constructive, and will most likely be closed by the community. From [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/):

> Constructive subjective questions:
>
> 1. inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
> 2. tend to have long, not short, answers.
> 3. have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
> 4. invite sharing experiences over opinions.
> 5. insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
> 6. are more than just mindless social fun.

Also, let's go back to the fact that you're asking our community to build you a list of books. We're the experts. Ask us! Tell us what you're problem is. We're more than happy, and qualified, to help! While your question will probably be closed, you can edit it and improve it, highlighting the real problem that you're trying to solve and focusing on the solution.

Consider these two examples from [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for guidance on how you can edit your post:

**Bad Question:**

> **Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?**
>
> A: Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.
>
> A: No! Pentax is the best, the NX4!
>
> A: I like the Canon Rebel G. It's awesome!
>
> A: Me too! I only use Canons.

NOTE: The last 3 answers were added by me to demonstrate how confusing and unhelpful list/poll questions can be. There's no right answer, and no explanations.

**Good Question after Edits:**

> **Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos?**
>
> A: I strongly recommend looking for something with
>
> - a fast lens (2.0 at least)
> - reasonable ISO handling (at least 400, but preferably 800)
> - the biggest sensor available
>
> The sum of these factors are really critical for low light situations.

This question leads to explanations and guidance on how to come to a solution. This is much more helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you should read. tl;dr shows how much you care to answer with honesty.

Comment: First point : Constructive subjective questions:
inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
That is what my first question which I posted was supposed to do but, a stereotypical explanation will say "it attracts subjective answers" where there is 'how' there is a debate.

Comment: Sorry, the tl;dr was to summarize what I wrote, in case you were too overwhelmed to read my entire post.  Let me edit that to something that maybe makes more sense.

Comment: Actually, Stack Overflow is for the more objective style questions, where the question really only has one (or a few) correct, verifiable answers. Programmers SE does handle questions about the software development process, which is why I suggested your question would be more on topic there, once you focus on solutions, not books or links. Hope this helps! :)